# Форма выбора как в 1С только для Web

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, битрикс, 1с

Кто знает есть ли готовое решение для подбора товара или какого другого элемента реализованных как в 1С. В частности интересует реализация для Yii2 но и примеров с подобной реализацией будет тоже достаточно.[image: Фрагмент 1С]

Comment: А что именно нужно то?

Comment: vnn198 на изо видно три точки для подбора номенклатуры, после нажатия открывается окно для подбора и выбора товара (в web modal) оно по суте отображает в точности справочник номенклатуры за иключением того что можно выбрать товар и перенести его в документ, а так же в случае необходимости можно создать новый товар если его нет в справочнике. Я написал нечто подобное но мне не нравиться реализация поэтому хотел узнать сталкивался ли кто с подобными задачами.

Comment: Тут наверное нужен какой-то UI/UX движек, но всёравно многое надо будет писать вручную.

Comment: Ишите по словам "javascript datagrid". Масса всяких движков для табличек. Навскидку extJs (платная, можно полностью приложение построить), w2ui (бесплатная на jQuery), jQueryUI